# Line detection of matplotlib.pyplot image not working with cv hough transformation

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

[This is the input image with output i achieved while tweaking some parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIjga.png)i've been trying to detect lines of a matplotlib.pyplot image representing a floorplan. But when tweaking the hyperparameters of cv2 I either get a lot of random lines or no lines at all I've no idea what i'm doing wrong. The image contains colored shapes without noise so I can't image why the detection is failing. Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

The input matrix is a 50x50 2d matrix containing integers that represent room types like bathroom = 1 , kitchen = 2,..

I represent the matrix like this in a plot:

```
plt.imshow(floorplan, cmap='viridis', interpolation='nearest') 
plt.show()
```

This is my code for detecting lines

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Define the matrix
matrix = floorplan

# Add a 1-pixel border to the matrix
matrix = cv2.copyMakeBorder(matrix, 1, 1, 1, 1, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=0)

# Define the room types
room_types = {1: 'KITCHEN', 2: 'OFFICE_1 room', 3: 'OFFICE_2', 4: 'BATHROOM',
              5: 'MEETING', 6:'CORRIDOR'}

# Define the line detection parameters
rho = 1  # distance resolution in pixels
theta =np.pi/180,  # angle resolution in radians
threshold = 75  # minimum number of votes to consider a line
min_line_length = 5  # minimum length of a line in pixels
max_line_gap = 3  # maximum gap between line segments to consider them as a single line

# Apply the Hough Line Transform to the matrix
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(
    image=np.uint8(matrix),
    rho=rho,
    theta=theta,
    threshold=threshold,
    minLineLength=min_line_length,
    maxLineGap=max_line_gap,
)
plt.imshow(matrix, cmap='gray')
# Draw the lines on a blank image
line_img = np.zeros_like(matrix)
for line in lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
    cv2.line(line_img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), 255, 1)

# Add a 1-pixel border to the line_img
line_img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(line_img, 1, 1, 1, 1, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=0)

# Calculate the room types in each space between the lines
spaces = np.zeros_like(matrix)
for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
    for j in range(matrix.shape[1]):
        if line_img[i, j] == 0:
            space = np.zeros_like(matrix)
            cv2.floodFill(space.astype('uint8'), mask=line_img.astype('uint8'), seedPoint=(j, i), newVal=255)
            if np.sum(space) > 0:
                counts = {k: 0 for k in room_types.keys()}
                for x, y in zip(*np.where(space == 255)):
                    room_type = int(matrix[x, y])
                    counts[room_type] += 1
                most_common_room_type = max(counts, key=counts.get)
                matrix[np.where(space == 255)] = most_common_room_type

# Remove the 1-pixel border from the matrix
matrix = matrix[1:-1, 1:-1]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(matrix, cmap='viridis')


plt.imshow(matrix, cmap='gray')

# Plot the lines on top of the image
for line in lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
    plt.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2], color='r')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

I tried tweaking the hyperparameters the threshold, the theta, the rho,... I expected to get more realistic detection but either got more random lines or no lines at all.

Comment: Please provide the input image

Comment: @coder00 i added an image containing input after gray scaling and output i once achieved